# CSS Flexbox - How do I create a flexbox of items inside a <p> tag that wraps on overflow but starts the new row after the initial text in the <p> tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox, that wraps on overflow, and when it moves to a new row due to horizontal overflow, I would want it to start the new row aligned with the start of the first row's items. The flexbox would be within a

tag, and there would be some text before the flexbox is created, but I would want the start of the next row of the flexbox to be after the text. I will show a simple drawing of how it should look like.

```
text...... *flexbox starts* *end of row*
           *next row starts if horizontal overflow*
```

I am new to CSS and flexbox, do guide me along if I am missing anything! Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `flex-wrap` on the container of the wrappable items. Also make sure the text isn't in the flexbox. Here's an example:

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div>Here's some text...</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:800px;
}

.outer-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/annaazzam/pen/LYGeQag

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different `div` for your text and your flex-items.

```
.wrapper {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
}
.container {
display:flex;
flex-wrap : wrap;
width:600px
}
.container .box {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
<p>Some text...</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
<div class="box box4"></div>
<div class="box box5"></div>
<div class="box box6"></div>
</div>
</div>
```